Numerical solver for a Hamilton Jacobi equation with nonconvex and nonsmooth hamiltonian.
I have a Hamilton-Jacobi equation that comes from a particular zero sum differentiable game. For such games the associated Hamilton Jacobi Isaac (HJI) equation, has a Hamitonian $H(.)$ that is both nonconvex and non-differentiable. The HJI equation I have is of the form:
$$ \partial_tu+H(\partial_x u)=0,$$
with the terminal condition $u(x,T)=g(x)$. The Hamiltonian can be assumed to be Lipschitz continuous. The terminal function is bounded and lipschitz continuous. My question is whether there exist any known scheme which has a theoretically guaranteed convergence? My problem is low dimensional so I am not worried about the "curse of dimensionality".
